# $.ajax always going to error, why?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

my code is like this:

```
    var WebServiceURL = "CityFixWS.asmx"; //the same as above. only with…

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#LoginPage", function () {
wireEventsLoginPage();
});

function wireEventsLoginPage() {
$('#LPBtnCheckUserByIDPass').click(function () {
    debugger;
    var id = $('#LPUserIDTXT').val();
    var pass = $('#LPUserPassTXT').val();

    var user = {
        idPar: id,
        passPar: pass
    }

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: WebServiceURL + "/GetUserByNamePass",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "get", 
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var res = data.d;
            var resOutput = JSON.parse(res);
            alert("res=" + res);
            alert("resOutput= " + resOutput);
            if (resOutput != 'ERROR USER!') {
                alert(resOutput.Address + ", " + resOutput.Name);
                var jqHomePage = $("#HomePage");
                $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", jqHomePage, {});
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERRRRRRRRRROR");
        },
    });
    alert('END');
});
```

and i saw with the debugger that when it came to $.ajax row always the next step is error.... 
hmm... what i am trying to do is to check the user details before he login

and this is the request web method

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetUserByNamePass(int userID, string passPar)
{
    User user = null;
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    command.CommandText =
        " SELECT * " +
        " FROM Users " +
        " WHERE User_ID = @user_ID AND Password = @pass";

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user_ID", userID));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", passPar));
    command.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        user = new User()
        {
            Id = (int)reader["User_ID"],
            Full_Name = reader["Full_Name"].ToString(),
            Birthday = (DateTime)reader["Birthday"],
            Password = reader["Password"].ToString(),
            ReportsCount = (int)reader["ReportCounts"]
        };
        command.Connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
        return json.Serialize(user);
    }
    else
    {
        command.Connection.Close();
        return json.Serialize("ERROR USER!");
    }
}
```

}

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="CityFixJS.js">
</script>
```

this is the button that i need to click on it

```
'<input type="button" id="LPBtnCheckUserByIDPass" value="התחבר" />'
```

Comment: Did you actually try looking at the error? What does it say?

Comment: We need more information about the request being made. If it's going to error, there's a reason... currently you don't seem to be looking for a reason.

Comment: wait, do you mean to show you what is the request ? .cs page
any way i'll edit

Comment: no... we don't need to see your server-side code. not yet. we need response headers and body.

Comment: ok, i'll copy the header

Comment: more details ? sorry for my english :/

Comment: er, uhm... those aren't the headers.

Comment: so can you give me an example of header ?

Comment: `Request URL:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43374131/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:204 No Content
Remote Address:151.101.193.69:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade` of course, omit anything private.

Comment: this is the error output while debugging, POST http://localhost:50648/CityFixWS.asmx/GetUserByNamePass 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Cool. now this is no longer a client-side problem. You need to get the error message from the server.

Comment: if you see the alert("ERRROOORR!"), this is what always shown..

Comment: so what would the problem be ?

Comment: No idea. you need to add some debugging server-side.

Answer (score -1):

I think its a parsing error, try removing dataType: 'json', and see if it works.

Comment: because it's a wild guess. Probably correct, but until the question is clarified it can't be accurately answered.